# Finding a solution for ratio problem

Tags: linear-algebra, gre-exam

[image]

I understand how to get the answer but can't we write explicitly the condition as a equation? I mean i have done this with length process, I need a quick process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question, but wouldn't simply adding speeds serve your purpose? $\frac{1plot}{2h} + \frac{1plot}{4h}  = \frac{6plots}{8h} = \frac{3 plots}{4h} = \frac{1plot}{4/3 h}$

Comment: why $\frac{4}{3}$ arises?

Comment: well, if one does half a plot per hour and the other does a quarter of a plot per hour, together they will do three quarters of a plot per hour. This means they need $\frac{4}{3}$ hours to do a plot!

Comment: Then your equation goes to $$\frac{1plot}{2h} + \frac{1plot}{4h} = \frac{1plot}{3/4 h}$$ isn't it?

Comment: Careful there (see my edit). Together they do $3/4$ of a plot per hour, which means $\frac{3/4 plot}{1h}$, not the other way around.